# How to read Javascript errors?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to run a basic Vue JS app, on my local machine, that uses the materialize-css navbar (https://materializecss.com/navbar.html). On running this app in the terminal, I'm getting the following error.

```
This relative module was not found:

* ./components/Navbar in ./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--12-0!./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/App.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&
```

What is this error trying to say? How to correct this?

Comment: It's saying that Webpack cannot find your `/components/Navbar` module from `./src/App.vue`

Comment: Sorry, that's `./components/Navbar` (copy / paste error)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the name of my navbar file. In my code, it was "Navbar" while in my local directory was "NavBar".